# SQL - Need to count entries related to an id and other attributes

Tags: mysql

So i have two databases, one about movies, one about actors.
I need a new database which includes the amount of movies in which each actor has partecipated.

```
SELECT Count(title) as MovieTotal
FROM movie
    JOIN actors
        ON film.actorsID = actors.ID
GROUP BY actors.id
```

This almost works, but I want the actors first and second name to be shown next to the count.. any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the columns you want to the SELECT and use those for your GROUP BY.

```
SELECT actors.firstName, actors.secondName, Count(title) as MovieTotal
FROM movie
    JOIN actors
        ON film.actorsID = actors.ID
GROUP BY actors.firstName, actors.secondName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm a newbie to SQL and I'm struggling a lot tonight